# if $0 → W → V → V/W → 0$ is a short exact sequence of $\mathfrak{g}$-representations then $B_V = B_{W} + B_{V/W}$

Tags: lie-algebras, exact-sequence

Show that if $0 → W → V → V/W → 0$ is a short exact
sequence of $\mathfrak{g}$-representations then $B_V = B_{W} + B_{V/W}$ where $\mathfrak{g}$ is a lie algebra.
$B $ is a bilinear form on $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $B(x,y)=tr(\rho(x) \rho(y))$

I don't know how to relate trace to this short sequece. I think I should use the fact that evert short exact sequece of vector spaces splits. Then, $\rho(x) \rho(y)$ can be written as sum of two matrices, one in $End(W)$ and one in $End(V/W)$? Can any one give a hint?

Comment: I would try to use the fact that the matrix of $\rho_V(x)$ has the blockform
$$\rho_V(x)=\pmatrix{\rho_W(x)&*\cr 0&\rho_{V/W}(x)\cr}$$
for all $x\in\mathfrak{g}$. Here $*$ denotes a rectangular matrix we don't know about. It could be replaced with a zero block, if your short exact sequence splits as $\mathfrak{g}$-modules.